# T-Sql - Pivot Error

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot, pivot-table

I have the following code in a T-Sql query, I am getting the following error message and I am not really sure what is causing the error.  I am writing the Pivot statement to be dynamic b/c I do not know the columns that will be returned.

Error Message: Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The column 'Title - Endorsement Fee / END8' was specified multiple times for 'PivotTable'.

The Temp Table #FeeTotals has 3 columns 1) dwordrkey (unique id key), 2) Desc_Cd: description of the charge, 3) Total: a money column

```
    DECLARE @PivotColumnHeaders VARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @PivotColumnHeaders = 
      COALESCE(
        @PivotColumnHeaders + ',[' + cast(Desc_Cd as varchar) + ']',
        '[' + cast(Desc_cd as varchar)+ ']'
      )
    From #FeeTotals

    DECLARE @PivotTableSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @PivotTableSQL = N'
    Select *
    From #FeeTotals
    PIVOT
      (
   Sum(Total)
   For Desc_Cd In (' + @PivotColumnHeaders + ')
  )
    As PivotTable'

    Execute(@PivotTableSQL)
```

Comment: For debugging, can you replace the EXECUTE with PRINT.  Then you can review the actual statement that fails.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to select `DISTINCT` values of Desc_Cd From #FeeTotals when creating the headers. It must be in there twice. Also use the `QuoteName` function so your code deals with any `Desc_Cd` values that contain the `]` character correctly.

```
DECLARE @PivotColumnHeaders NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @PivotColumnHeaders = 
COALESCE(@PivotColumnHeaders + ',' + Desc_Cd, Desc_Cd)
    FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT QUOTENAME(Desc_Cd) AS Desc_Cd
    FROM #FeeTotals
    ) F
```